# How to get local mapping of a servlet in its init method?

Tags: java, servlets

I've a servlet and it's init method must do some HTTP calls to itself. This is because I'm using an embedded app, that starts up and it's main interface it's a RESTful API. I can't and don't really want to use the internal classes, because they are not documented and difficult to use. So I prefere to use the REST API through local HTTP.

So, I extended the servlet that comes with the App and I modified the init method, so that it *starts a thread and it does some HTTP calls to itself*. For the moment I hardwired "`http://localhost:port/servlet/mapping/`" as the path, but I'd like to have something dynamic that could at least detect the port number and the mapping too.

Is there any decent way to do this? I found lots of examples that extract that information from the `HttpServletRequest` object, but in the init method you don't have it. All you have is the `ServletContext`.

Ah, by the way, I use servlet API 3.0.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by doing HTTP calls to itself? the servlet container won't make the servlet available for HTTP calls until its `init()` method has finished

Comment: If you read carefully, I wrote "So I start a thread that does the HTTP calls". The init method will terminate after starting the thread and the thread will carry on doing the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In servlets 3 you can do this to get current mappings for a given servlet:

```
String servletName = servletConfig.getServletName();
ServletRegistration reg = servletConfig.getServletContext().getServletRegistration(servletName);
for(String mapping: reg.getMappings()) {
    // Do something with the mapping
}
```

About the port number, given the fact that a servlet container can be "listening" on more than one port, there is no standard way you can know the port number even if there is only one.